# Compare Unequal Entities

Tags: statistics, soft-question

This is more of like an analytic question. It could be vague but let me try to narrow it down a little. Assuming, i am working on an analysis in primary education which include factors like

```
students
courses
teachers
finance.
```

I have all this data with me. it will make sense to compare this data to an entity of almost equal standing like another junior school.But how about when i want to compare the results gotten from the primary education to "University education" ?. It's obvious that the University will have more

```
students
courses
teachers
finance.
```

But i need to compare in the sense that :

What if this primary school was a University ? Will the stats be around the same ? will the results be normal. Thus, i need to know how to put both of these entities at the same level so i can equally compare. How can i go about doing this ?

My excuses if this is on the wrong platform, i don't know where precisely to ask this. If my tags are wrong, kindly edit.